# Obtain compiled SQL string from SimpleJdbcInsertOperations.java

Tags: java, jdbc

I inherited a large codebase that uses **SimpleJdbcInsertOperations.java** for simple DB inserts. I know this class internally compiles an SQL statement behind the scenes from the map passed to the **execute** method.  I need a way to get that SQL string from the object. Below is a sample code snippet...

```
private int insertIntoTable(){

    SimpleJdbcInsertOperations simpleJdbcInsertOperations = new SimpleJdbcInsert(
            MY_JDBC_TEMPLATE).withSchemaName(MY_SCHEMA).withTableName(MY_TABLE);

    //Map the columns for query
    Map<String, Object> myArguments = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myArguments.put("COLUMN1", "1");
    myArguments.put("COLUMN2", "2");

    //TODO - NEED WAY TO GET COMPILED SQL STATEMENT


    return simpleJdbcInsertOperations.execute(myArguments);

}
```

Please no replies like "why not use jdbcTemplate instead?" The codebase is far too expensive to change at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Wow This was easy to fix. Instead of using SimpleJdbcInsertOperations, I just changed the object reference to SimpleJdbcInsert. Then I can call SimpleJdbcInsert.getInsertString()